# Increment then decrementing every other 10

Tags: javascript

I'm building a draft app for fantasy. Because of this every 10 picks, the teams pick backwards. Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to write a long if/else, switch, ext statment?

example:

- Pick  Team
- 1  -   1
- 2  -  2
- 3  - 3
- 4  -4
- 5  -   5
- 7  -   7
- 8  -   8
- 9  -   9
- 10 -   10
- 11  -   10
- 12  -   9
- and so on

Comment: How about your code?

Comment: Use a variable to hold a multiplier, either `+1` or `-1`. Whenever the pick is a multiple of 10, switch the sign.

Comment: `10 - |10 - n|` + `% 20`

Answer (score 0):

make a boolean variable storing weather we are incrementing or decrementing, then a byte to store how many times you have incremented/decremented, and make a loop. use an if/else with the boolean. do not forget to flip the boolean each time.

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this should get the job done:**

```
var total_picks = 100;
var current_pick = 1;
var current_team = 1;
var my_test = true;

for (var i = 0; i < total_picks; i++) {

  // In this "if" statement, the team number will count up from 1 to 10
  if (my_test) {

    // Do whatever you want to with the current pick here
    current_pick++;

    // Do whatever you want to with the current team here
    current_team++;

    if (current_team == 10) {
      my_test = false;
    }
  } else {
    // In this "else" statement, the team number will count down from 10 to 1

    // Do whatever you want to with the current pick here
    current_pick++;

    // Do whatever you want to with the current team here
    current_team--;
    if (current_team == 0) {
      my_test = true;
    }
  }
}
```